# Spring security doesn't match a given role

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing a simple spring security app that has 3  user roles(emp,admin,man). I read user data  by datasource and also i have my own access-denied page for the situation that any user wants to access to forbidden pages. before I used to define my user information(username, password, roles) on my java class DemoSecurityConfig in the method `protected void configure ()` and spring security could notice what page each user can access but the problem is that since I am reading the information  from the database all my users directed to the access denied page which means spring security roles don't work or it can't read the given role

**DemoSecurityConfig class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
   private DataSource securityDataSource;
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       //use jdbc
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);

    }
    //configure of web patch in application login logout

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("emp")
        .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasAnyRole("man")
                .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasAnyRole("admin")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

}
```

**DemoAppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-mysql.properties")
public class DemoAppConfig  {
    //define a bean for view resolver
    @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
      InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return  viewResolver;
    }
        //reading properties file

    //set yp varible for holding a properties
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    private Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    //define a bean for data source

    @Bean
    public DataSource securityDataSource(){
    //create data connection
        ComboPooledDataSource securityDataSource
                =new ComboPooledDataSource();
        //set up jdbc driver class
        try {
            securityDataSource.setDriverClass(env.getProperty("jdbc.driver"));
        } catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw  new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        //log the connection for make sure
       logger.info(">> jdbc.url=" +env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info(">> jdbc.user=" +env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        //set up database connection properties
securityDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        securityDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        securityDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        //set yp connection props
        securityDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        securityDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        securityDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));
        securityDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));




        return securityDataSource;
    }
//need a helper class
    //read env property and convert to int
    private int getIntProperty(String proName){
        String proVal=env.getProperty(proName);
        int intPropVal=Integer.parseInt(proVal);
                return intPropVal;
    }

}
```

home.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>this is a main page</h1>
<!-- add link to point to leaders   -->
<security:authorize access="hasRole('admin')">
<p>
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/systems">IT meeting</a>
    (only for admins)
</p>
<br/>
<p>

    </security:authorize>
    <security:authorize access="hasRole('man')">
    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/leaders">leaders meeting</a>
    (only for admins)
</p>
<br/>
</security:authorize>
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout"  method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout">

    <hr>
        <-- display user -->
    User: <security:authentication property="principal.username"/>
    <br><br>
    roles <security:authentication property="principal.authorities"/>

    </hr>

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `hasAnyRole()` [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/latest/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.AuthorizedUrl.html#hasAnyRole-java.lang.String...-) :

> Shortcut for specifying URLs require any of a number of roles. If you
>   do not want to have "ROLE_" automatically inserted see
>   hasAnyAuthority(String...)

So `hasAnyRole("emp")` expects the user has the role `ROLE_emp` but the user has the role `emp` now .

Either update all user authorities in database to be prefixed with `ROLE_` such as `ROLE_emp` and `ROLE_admin` or change to use `hasAnyAuthority()`  which will not add the `ROLE_` prefix :

```java
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").hasAnyAuthority("emp")
            .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasAnyAuthority("man")
            .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasAnyAuthority("admin")
            ......

    }
```