# Spring security not directed where I should be

Tags: java, spring

In database I have table `authorities` and inside I have column authority, that column is populated and in this case with `ROLE_MANAGER`, also I have this inside my `configure` method in extends class `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

`.antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")` I also have more of this but that is not important. As you can see, `MANAGER` which I also have in mysql. This is on my home page.

```
<security:authorize access="hasRole('MANAGER')">

    <!-- Add a link to point to /leaders ... this is for the managers -->
    
    <p>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/leaders">Leadership Meeting</a>
        (Only for Manager peeps)
    </p>

</security:authorize>
```

This is that `leaders` mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/leaders")
    public String showLeaders() {
        
        return "leaders";
    }
```

But when I log in with user which have role manager program send me on my page which says Im not authorized to view that content, but If I log in with user which has both role, `ROLE_MANAGER` and `ROLE_ADMIN` I can see that `/leaders` page.

What can be a problem? I dont know what to try, everything seems fine, idk why wont work. I figured out that just users which has all roles can acess, If user have just one role that user cant access page that he should

[I shared project on git](https://github.com/jankostefan/spring_project)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following page, someone asked a question like yours before:

[Spring security doesn't match a given role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62375760/spring-security-doesnt-match-a-given-role)

Comment: its same, idk what to try